# Uncaught syntax error: ) missing after argument list in asp.net mvc application javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, onclick, typeerror

I have researched on why we get "Uncaught Syntax error: ) missing after argument list" error and i went through my code throughly, after reading a few answers on stack overflow. i've been on this for more than a day, yet the error still persist. please help.

my code

```
function openinnewtab(filename) {
    var url = @Url.Action("DisplayDocuments", new { Filename = filename });
    var redirectWindow = window.open(url, '_blank');
    redirectWindow.location.reload(true);
    return false;
}
```

and i am calling it here in my View, basically im tring tto implement onclick functionality on the image so as when the image is clicked, it opens a new window and displays the image.

```
<a onclick="openinnewtab(@filename);"><img title="@filename" src="~/Content/images/image.png"></a>
```

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if that helps you in fixing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are missing some `single quotes` and also you are mixing `JS` variables in `Razor` Code, your code should be -

```
<a onclick="openinnewtab('@filename');"><img title="@filename" src="~/Content/images/image.png"></a>
```

And

```
   function openinnewtab(filename) {
     var url = '@Url.Action("DisplayDocuments", new { Filename = "tempFileName" })';

     // Replace templFileName with actual value which is being passed to this function
     url = url.replace("tempFileName", filename);
     var redirectWindow = window.open(url, '_blank');
     redirectWindow.location.reload(true);
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: hey @ramiramilu  thanks! I missed those single quotes. I am a beginner. in both asp.net n js